# Getting the user's email account through login

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-chrome-app

I am working on my first chrome app and am trying to learn by digging through some of the sample apps.  Right now I am working with the gdrive app (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/gdrive).

The README says that this app "uses the chrome.identity.getAuthToken() API to perform OAuth2 and access the Google Drive API."

When you authorize the app, a screen pops up confirming your authorization and in the top right corner it has the email you are trying to sign in with (johndoe@gmail.com).

I want to save "johndoe@gmail.com" as a string so I can display it when the user is logged in.

Does anyone know how I would go about doing that?  I am fairly new to using these APIs, so I am a bit clueless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to display the name that the user probably wants you to display ("Eric Austin" in your case). https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/identity demonstrates how to do this. Look for the `displayName` field in the personal data response.

If you really want to display the user's email address (and take the risk that many users will decline to give your app access to their contact information), check out [Google's OAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) and follow the steps to obtain the id_token listed in Step 5.